# Custom Preference that can listen for changes to a preference value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm creating a custom Preference that allows the user to select an image from the gallery. To do this, I set its Intent to one that starts an intermediate translucent activity that in turn starts an Activity with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, and in `startActivityForResult` persists the URI of whatever the user selected.

(Actually, I save the file to internal memory with a constant name, and persist a long with a timestamp, but I think that's irrelevant to my question.)

Now I'd like to update an ImageView I'm using in the Preference subclass's `setWidget` space with the newly selected image. How can a custom Preference class listen for changes to its own preference key's value?

I'm setting the image without issue in `onBindView()`, but this is only called when the preference screen is getting laid out. I've looked at the source of various built-in Preferences, and none of them have this issue because none of them open an Activity for making the preference selection. They all have a dialog that can call back to the preference, or perform their action internally with `onClick()`.

However, I can't think of a way to get the user to select a gallery image without using an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` Activity.

I know I could add a public method, and then use a OnSharedPreferenceChangedListener in my PreferenceActivity to manually call back to the Preference to update itself. But I want to put this class in a library to use in multiple projects (and possibly later publish in an open source library), and so requiring all those manual steps is very ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check [`RingtonePreference`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/preference/RingtonePreference.java)? This launches an ringtone picker activity and handles the result by registering itself as an `PreferenceManager.OnActivityResultListener` listener, so it will get delegated to by the owning Activity.

Choice snippet from the source code:

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToHierarchy(PreferenceManager preferenceManager) {
    super.onAttachedToHierarchy(preferenceManager);

    preferenceManager.registerOnActivityResultListener(this);
    mRequestCode = preferenceManager.getNextRequestCode();
}

public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == mRequestCode) {

        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

            if (callChangeListener(uri != null ? uri.toString() : "")) {
                onSaveRingtone(uri);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

EDIT:

---

```
public class TestPreference extends Preference implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    public TestPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public TestPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TestPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToHierarchy(PreferenceManager preferenceManager) {
        super.onAttachedToHierarchy(preferenceManager);
        getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals(getKey())) {
            // Update myself
        }
    }
}
```

And your activity then updates the preference in `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Name of shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    // OR use default
    // SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    preferences.edit().putString("custom_preference_key", "VALUE").apply();
}
```

Comment: I overlooked RingtonePreference. Still can't get it to work internally to my class though. PreferenceManager's `getActivity()`/`getFragment()` are package protected. So I can set the Preference's Intent, but since the Preference doesn't know what Activity owns it, it can't call `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't realize those methods were package private. Could you update the preference key in `onActivityResult` and listen for the change in your preference? See updated answer.

Comment: That works! Nice. I do realize, there is still one barrier to this being a totally clean solution--the intermediate Activity must be registered in every project that uses it. But at least it's just a one-liner now.

Comment: You shouldn't have to register it in every project - if you define it in your library's manifest, manifest merging should include it in the consuming app's final manifest: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html